# Kubuntu 17.10 / Plasma 5.10 / Default permission for new files created in Dolphin

Tags: linux, file-permissions, kubuntu, kde-plasma-5, dolphin-file-manager

My machine is shared by multiple users. I have set up folders where files reside that more than one person needs to work on. For the remainder of this text let `/srv/files/documents` be the folder we talk about, and `team` be the name of a group where everyone belongs to.

- I've set `umask` to `0002` in `/etc/login.defs`
- I've set setguid bit and permissions on `/srv/files/documents` (`u=rwx,g=rwxs,o=rx`)
- I've set `/srv/files/document`'s group changed to `team`

In the following cases, a new file is created with group set to `team` and permissions set to `664`:

- From VTx: `touch /srv/files/documents/test`
- From Konsole started in Plasma session: `touch /srv/files/documents/test`
- From LibreOffice: Save file as...
- From Kate: Save file as...

So until now, I seem to have done everything correctly. Now, when I start Dolphin, navigate to `/srv/files/documents`, right-click and select New Text Document (or any other of the available file types), it create a new empty file with group set to `team` and permission set to **`644`** - which is not what I want.

Creating new folders in Dolphin correctly applies the group `team` and permissions `775`, btw.

I have already fiddled with ACL, but that didn't change anything. I do currently assume that - for whatever reason - Dolphin skips the g=w permission when creating a new file. I would expect this to be a setting that I could modify, if only I knew how. It's not in the regular settings dialog as far as I can tell.

Thanks in advance for any idea you like to share!

Patrick

Comment: Same problem on 16.04, but directories are created `drwxr-xr-x` despite a umask set to `077` (in the terminal sub-window, mkdir correctly creates the directory with `drwx------`). Time to report a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So until now, I seem to have done everything correctly. Now, when I
>   start Dolphin, navigate to /srv/files/documents, right-click and
>   select New Text Document (or any other of the available file types),
>   it create a new empty file with group set to team and **permission set
>   to 644** - which is not what I want.

Dolphin copies the **pre-installed** template files including file permissions (0644). To modify the permissions on Kubuntu 17.10 run:

```
sudo chmod 0664 /usr/share/templates/.source/*
```

New files will now be created with 0664 permissions.

Comment: Thanks, you just solved a long-lasting problem for me! I wasn't aware of this templates directory. Is this documented somewhere where regular users (like me) could read it? There are a couple other mysteries that I'd like to solve...